# What is the relation between ANSI and ISO regarding ISO 27000?

Tags: audit, iso27000, iso27001, governance

So in one answer I was told that ANSI is a governing body (the only one in the world) for ISO 27000? I think I got something wrong, because I don't see ANSI mentioned anywhere when I read about standards (not that I'm looking for that intentionaly). It's ISO everywhere! Can someone please try to explain me the difference between the two? Does ANSI actually have anything to do with ISO 27000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_National_Standards_Institute) stands for American National Standards Institute

[ISO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization) stands for International Organization for Standardization

ANSI is the American representative of the ISO body.

So, yes, ISO is the umbrella, but in the US, ANSI is the representative.

Comment: Would you know what's the representative in Europe?

Comment: Wikipedia identifies JTC1/SC27 and points to their website, which shows 52 participating countries and their (standards) organizations; choose the one(s) you want from http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/list_of_iso_technical_committees/iso_technical_committee_participation.htm?commid=45306 .

Comment: @Schroeder answers your question perfectly, but I'd feel remiss if I didn't point out that the 27000 family are ISO/IEC joint standard, not just ISO ones. The poor old IEC don't get no respect.